# Kerberos error when using integrated authentication

Tags: authentication, kerberos, http-authentication

I am getting following error when I authenticate a web page in IIS 6.0 :

Msg Type : KRB-ERROR (30)
error-code : KRB5KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED

can someone please suggest what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did not really want to use kerberos, but it was just holding me down. Anyway, figured out how to prevent this error. I simply disabled Negotiate in IIS server setting for the website. Chaged it from "negotiate, NTLM" to only "NTLM".

It uses NTLM now, which is fine for me.